# ¿Por qué mi menú desplegable, al cerrarlo, se esconde rápidamente y se vuelve a abrir y cerrar?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un menú para una web usando simplemente HTML y CSS. A la hora de hacer el menú hamburguesa, quiero que este se despliegue hacia abajo, desplazando el contenido que hay debajo del Header. Hasta ahí todo correcto. Lo que he hecho es usar un checkbox para controlar el estado del menú, es decir, si está abierto o cerrado (checked / not checked). A esto le he agregado una transición y animaciones... A la hora de desplegar el menú se comporta de la manera que yo quiero, pero a la hora de cerrarlo, tiene un comportamiento algo extraño. He estado buscando sobre esto a ver si a alguien más le ha pasado, pero no he encontrado nada.

Adjunto HTML y CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>SandBox</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="top">
    <a href="">Aviso Legal</a><span> |</span>
    <a href="">Mi cuenta</a>
  </div>
  <label for="menu"
    ><img src="menu.png" alt="menuIcon" width="40px"
  /></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu" />
  <div class="links">
    <a href="">Inicio</a>
    <a href="">Tienda</a>
    <a href="">Contacto</a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Contenido</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
    error officiis quisquam. Voluptatum vitae hic, laudantium nam voluptate
    similique itaque magni eius aliquid. Voluptate aut possimus obcaecati
    voluptates. In provident eum sit accusamus! Illum aut nobis possimus
    nisi et natus tenetur deleniti accusantium architecto laborum sapiente
    veniam neque molestiae, tempore placeat dolore ipsum ad! Ea, enim
    provident. Mollitia, minima numquam, voluptatum tempora aperiam quam
    maxime alias consequatur rerum nisi ipsam, provident iusto dolor!
    Necessitatibus, optio quibusdam! Provident repudiandae assumenda, optio
    minima officiis quam odit. Hic voluptas non quia distinctio? Perferendis
    debitis animi cumque repellat? Nostrum perspiciatis ullam ipsa delectus
    facilis?
  </p>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

El CSS es:

```
.top{
background-color: black;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
margin:auto;

}

.top a{
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-left: 10px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;

}

.top a:hover{
color: rgb(209, 178, 1);

}

.top span{
color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.548);
}

/*Escondemos el checkbox*/

header input[type="checkbox"]{
display: none;
}

header label{
display: block;
width: 40px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
cursor: pointer;

}

/*LINKS - CAJA*/
header .links{
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
display:block;
width: 100%;
height: 0px;
z-index: 10;

transition: all .5s ease;


}

.links a{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.links a:hover{
color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.747);

}


/*Accion menu*/
header input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .links{
animation: slide 0.8s ease .1s forwards;
background-color: black;
}

header input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .links{
animation: slideCancel .5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .3s forwards;
}

/*ANIMACION*/
@keyframes slide{
from {height: 0;}
to {height: 225px;}

}

@keyframes slideCancel{
from {height: 225px;}
to {height: 0px;}

}
```

Cuando ejecuto en el navegador, cuando voy a abrir el menú, se desplaza y aparece como yo quiero, pero al cerrar tiene un comportamiento raro, se esconde rápidamente y se vuelve a abrir y cerrar.

He probado con `backwards` en lugar de `forwards`, pero lo que hace es desaparecer el menú y esconderse de nuevo. Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué ocurre algo así, y cómo podría hacer para que el menú a la hora de cerrarse, lo hiciera progresivamente como cuando se abre?

```
header input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .links{
animation: slideCancel .5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .3s backwards;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Como tu código es HTML + CSS, podés [edit] tu pregunta y crear un snippet con el botón que indica `<>`, para poder reproducir el error desde la propia pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es por la [función de *easing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function) que escogiste para el cierre del menú:

```
cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045)
```

y por el tiempo que le diste a la duración y al *delay*.

La estructura que le diste a tu animación fue la siguiente:

| nombre | duración | función de *easing* | *delay* (tiempo de demora) | dirección |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *slideCancel* | .5s | `cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045)` | .3s | `forwards` |

Como le diste más tiempo al delay y relativamente menos duración, entonces se da como un efecto de "pestañeo" y desaparece casi de golpe.

Hay varias alternativas para cambiar este comportamiento.

- Una de ellas es darle más tiempo de duración y menos de *delay* (nótese que tiene un efecto "suave", similar al *fade*):

```css
.top {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.top a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
}

.top span {
  color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.548);
}


/*Escondemos el checkbox*/

header input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

header label {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*LINKS - CAJA*/

header .links {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.links a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.747);
}


/*Accion menu*/

header input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.links {
  animation: slide 0.8s ease .1s forwards;
  background-color: black;
}

header input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~.links {
  /*animation: slideCancel .5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .3s forwards;*/
  animation: slideCancel .8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .1s backwards;
}


/*ANIMACION*/

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 225px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideCancel {
  from {
    height: 225px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>SandBox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top">
      <a href="">Aviso Legal</a><span> |</span>
      <a href="">Mi cuenta</a>
    </div>
    <label for="menu"><img src="menu.png" alt="menuIcon" width="40px"
  /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu" />
    <div class="links">
      <a href="">Inicio</a>
      <a href="">Tienda</a>
      <a href="">Contacto</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1>Contenido</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error officiis quisquam. Voluptatum vitae hic, laudantium nam voluptate similique itaque magni eius aliquid. Voluptate aut possimus obcaecati voluptates. In provident eum sit accusamus!
      Illum aut nobis possimus nisi et natus tenetur deleniti accusantium architecto laborum sapiente veniam neque molestiae, tempore placeat dolore ipsum ad! Ea, enim provident. Mollitia, minima numquam, voluptatum tempora aperiam quam maxime alias consequatur
      rerum nisi ipsam, provident iusto dolor! Necessitatibus, optio quibusdam! Provident repudiandae assumenda, optio minima officiis quam odit. Hic voluptas non quia distinctio? Perferendis debitis animi cumque repellat? Nostrum perspiciatis ullam ipsa
      delectus facilis?
    </p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

- Si a la opción anterior se le agrega el `background-color` así como aparece al abrir el menú (es mucho más notoria la función de *easing*):

```css
.top {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.top a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
}

.top span {
  color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.548);
}


/*Escondemos el checkbox*/

header input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

header label {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*LINKS - CAJA*/

header .links {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.links a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.747);
}


/*Accion menu*/

header input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.links {
  animation: slide 0.8s ease .1s forwards;
  background-color: black;
}

header input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~.links {
  /*animation: slideCancel .5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .3s forwards;*/
  animation: slideCancel .8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .1s backwards;
  background-color: black;
}


/*ANIMACION*/

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 225px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideCancel {
  from {
    height: 225px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>SandBox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top">
      <a href="">Aviso Legal</a><span> |</span>
      <a href="">Mi cuenta</a>
    </div>
    <label for="menu"><img src="menu.png" alt="menuIcon" width="40px"
  /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu" />
    <div class="links">
      <a href="">Inicio</a>
      <a href="">Tienda</a>
      <a href="">Contacto</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1>Contenido</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error officiis quisquam. Voluptatum vitae hic, laudantium nam voluptate similique itaque magni eius aliquid. Voluptate aut possimus obcaecati voluptates. In provident eum sit accusamus!
      Illum aut nobis possimus nisi et natus tenetur deleniti accusantium architecto laborum sapiente veniam neque molestiae, tempore placeat dolore ipsum ad! Ea, enim provident. Mollitia, minima numquam, voluptatum tempora aperiam quam maxime alias consequatur
      rerum nisi ipsam, provident iusto dolor! Necessitatibus, optio quibusdam! Provident repudiandae assumenda, optio minima officiis quam odit. Hic voluptas non quia distinctio? Perferendis debitis animi cumque repellat? Nostrum perspiciatis ullam ipsa
      delectus facilis?
    </p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

- O, si querés que sea la misma transición que al abrir el menú, podrías usar la misma duración y el mismo delay, pero con dirección `backwards` en lugar de `forwards` (que ya la habías probado), y también agregando el `background-color`:

```css
.top {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.top a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
}

.top span {
  color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.548);
}


/*Escondemos el checkbox*/

header input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

header label {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*LINKS - CAJA*/

header .links {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.links a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.747);
}


/*Accion menu*/

header input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.links {
  animation: slide 0.8s ease .1s forwards;
  background-color: black;
}

header input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~.links {
  /*animation: slideCancel .5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .3s forwards;*/
   animation: slideCancel .8s ease .1s backwards;
 background-color: black;
}


/*ANIMACION*/

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 225px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideCancel {
  from {
    height: 225px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>SandBox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top">
      <a href="">Aviso Legal</a><span> |</span>
      <a href="">Mi cuenta</a>
    </div>
    <label for="menu"><img src="menu.png" alt="menuIcon" width="40px"
  /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu" />
    <div class="links">
      <a href="">Inicio</a>
      <a href="">Tienda</a>
      <a href="">Contacto</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1>Contenido</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error officiis quisquam. Voluptatum vitae hic, laudantium nam voluptate similique itaque magni eius aliquid. Voluptate aut possimus obcaecati voluptates. In provident eum sit accusamus!
      Illum aut nobis possimus nisi et natus tenetur deleniti accusantium architecto laborum sapiente veniam neque molestiae, tempore placeat dolore ipsum ad! Ea, enim provident. Mollitia, minima numquam, voluptatum tempora aperiam quam maxime alias consequatur
      rerum nisi ipsam, provident iusto dolor! Necessitatibus, optio quibusdam! Provident repudiandae assumenda, optio minima officiis quam odit. Hic voluptas non quia distinctio? Perferendis debitis animi cumque repellat? Nostrum perspiciatis ullam ipsa
      delectus facilis?
    </p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

- Y teniendo en cuenta la opción anterior, sin el `background-color` (también luce similar a *fade*):

```css
.top {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.top a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
}

.top span {
  color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.548);
}


/*Escondemos el checkbox*/

header input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

header label {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*LINKS - CAJA*/

header .links {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.links a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: rgb(209, 178, 1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.747);
}


/*Accion menu*/

header input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.links {
  animation: slide 0.8s ease .1s forwards;
  background-color: black;
}

header input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~.links {
  /*animation: slideCancel .5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045) .3s forwards;*/
   animation: slideCancel .8s ease .1s backwards;
}


/*ANIMACION*/

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 225px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideCancel {
  from {
    height: 225px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>SandBox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top">
      <a href="">Aviso Legal</a><span> |</span>
      <a href="">Mi cuenta</a>
    </div>
    <label for="menu"><img src="menu.png" alt="menuIcon" width="40px"
  /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu" />
    <div class="links">
      <a href="">Inicio</a>
      <a href="">Tienda</a>
      <a href="">Contacto</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1>Contenido</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error officiis quisquam. Voluptatum vitae hic, laudantium nam voluptate similique itaque magni eius aliquid. Voluptate aut possimus obcaecati voluptates. In provident eum sit accusamus!
      Illum aut nobis possimus nisi et natus tenetur deleniti accusantium architecto laborum sapiente veniam neque molestiae, tempore placeat dolore ipsum ad! Ea, enim provident. Mollitia, minima numquam, voluptatum tempora aperiam quam maxime alias consequatur
      rerum nisi ipsam, provident iusto dolor! Necessitatibus, optio quibusdam! Provident repudiandae assumenda, optio minima officiis quam odit. Hic voluptas non quia distinctio? Perferendis debitis animi cumque repellat? Nostrum perspiciatis ullam ipsa
      delectus facilis?
    </p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

> En todos los snippets el cambio está dentro de
> `header input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~.links`, debajo de la animación anterior (que está comentada para notar la diferencia).

<sub>(Me percaté que cada vez que se ejecuta el snippet, el menú tiene una animación de cierre. No contemplé eso en los códigos, y si eso es un problema, mejor escribir otra pregunta explicando ese problema ;) )</sub>

Comment: Otra observación: los cambios se notan mejor ejecutando los snippets en página completa.

Comment: Holaa Padaleiana! Los he estado probando con los diferentes ejemplos que me has pasado, y ahora todos se comportan como tal! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.